# Why doesn't this code return the correct result?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

```
Table Propositions
Table Invoices (proposition_id, total_left)
```

The goal is to return all propositions that have all their invoices's `total_left = 0`.

Example:

```
Proposition 1:
 Invoice 1, total_left: 0
 Invoice 2, total_left: 10

Proposition 2:
 Invoice 3, total_left: 0
 Invoice 4, total_left: 0
```

So in this example, the Proposition 2 should be returned, and not 1.

Here is the actual SQL.

```
SELECT
    "propositions".id
FROM
    "propositions"
    INNER JOIN "invoices" ON "invoices"."proposition_id" = "propositions"."id"
GROUP BY
    invoices.total_left,
    propositions.id
HAVING
    sum(invoices.total_left) = 0.0
```

But it doesn't work, it still returns Proposition Ids that have invoices with `total_left > 0`.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the `invoices.total_left` from `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  propositions.id
FROM
  propositions
  INNER JOIN invoices ON invoices.proposition_id = propositions.id
GROUP BY
  propositions.id
HAVING
  SUM(invoices.total_left) = 0.0
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=fbfcb7ae3ce17e992c82f74f03c020ee)

You get to much groups by using `invoices.total_left` on `GROUP BY`. You also don't get the expected `SUM` of each `propositions.id` because you have multiple records with the same `propositions.id` (but different `invoices.total_left`).

Since you want to know the `SUM` of `invoices.total_left` of each `propositions.id` you only need to `GROUP BY` the `propositions.id` column.

Comment: Is looks like it's working, I'll test more example, but can you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, the `join` is almost certainly unnecessary:

```
SELECT i.proposition_id
FROM invoices i
GROUP BY i.proposition_id
HAVING SUM(i.total_left) = 0.0;
```

You would only need the `JOIN` if you had `proposition_id` values in `invoices` that are not in `propositions`.  That seems highly unlikely in a well-formed data model.